# Meaning of brackets in variance equation

Tags: summation, variance

In this equation for calculating variance, do the brackets indicate an operation, or are they just like parenthesis?

[image: va]

Comment: Like parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have to multiply$\frac{1}{n-1}$ by whole

It is there just to prevent a misunderstanding